# GloboNote install error

Tags: 20.04, updates, java

I'm a begginer of ubuntu(20.04) and gonna install GloboNote.
I followed several guides in google but failed.

From the start, downloaded GloboNote on globonote.info/download and unzip that.
Then install java by command 'sudo apt install default-jre' and open with openjdk java 11 runtime(same as doubleclick) GloboNote.jar file, and problem occurs.

The picture below is the message(System tray is not supported on your system. Try to download latest version of java) I received right after doubleclicking that file.

So what I've done is uninstalling jre by 'sudo apt-get autoremove default-jdk openjdk-11-jre' and reinstall by command 'sudo apt install default-jre' again(cause I couldn't find any command that updates jre not just installing).

1. So I'm thinking my fault is didn't updating java - in this case I want to know the command updating jre appropriately.
2. but if its not about updating jre, I don't even know what the problem is. Can you tell me what to do step by step?

[image]

Comment: This is the latest version details GloboNote 1.6 - Sep. 21, 2020 Are you sure this app works on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: FYI it works normally on Ubuntu MATE 20.04.3 LTS. You have to find a way to enable tray on GNOMEs Hell.

Comment: @N0rbert You mean GNOME shell extension is needed? If its not, I cannot find the way to enable tray on gnome shell. By the way, how did you visualize that image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible on GNOME Shell. They break this classical user experience as a tradition.
So you have to install other desktop environment. The most comfortable at present time is [MATE](https://mate-desktop.org/) as in [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/).

So you have to open terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

then logout and login to MATE session and then and install GloboNote and launch it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre libcanberra-gtk-module
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://sourceforge.net/projects/globonote/files/globonote/GloboNote-1.6/globonote-1.6.tar.gz
tar -xf globonote-1.6.tar.gz
cd GloboNote/
./run.sh
```

to see GloboNote fully functional:

[image: GloboNote on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS]